# Boost.Python and C++ std::vector of pointers

Tags: python, pointers, boost, vector

I'm using Boost.Python to create a wrapper for my C++ library, and I'm having some troubles, googling all the day did not produc any results. For example, I have the following code:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void func() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual void func()
    {
        cout << "Derived::func()"<< endl;
    }
};


// wrapper for Base
struct BaseWrapper : Base, python::wrapper<Base>
{
    virtual void func()
    {
        this->get_override("func");
    }
};


Base* makeDerived()
{
    return new Derived;
}

vector<Base*>* makeDerivedVec()
{
    vector<Base*> *v = new vector<Base*>;
    v->push_back(new Derived);
    v->push_back(new Derived);
    v->push_back(new Derived);
    return v;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(mylib)
{
    // export Base
    class_<BaseWrapper, noncopyable>("Base")
            .def("func", pure_virtual(&Base::func));

    class_<vector<Base*> >("BasePtrVec")
            .def(vector_indexing_suite<vector<Base*> >());

    // export Derived
    class_<Derived, bases<Base> >("Derived")
            .def("func", &Derived::func);

    // export makeDerived()
    def("makeDerived", &makeDerived, return_value_policy<manage_new_object>());

    // export makeDerivedVec()
    def("makeDerivedVec", &makeDerivedVec, return_value_policy<manage_new_object>());
}
```

So, I compile it, import in python and try this:

> b = mylib.Base() b.func()
>
> d = mylib.makeDerived() d.func()

The first line, as expected, throws an exception saying that b.func() is pure virtual, and the second line prints out

> Derived::func()

And that's ok.

But the code

```
dlist = mylib.makeDerivedVec()
for d in dlist:
    d.func()
```

does not work, and Python throws an exception:

```
TypeError: No to_python (by-value) converter found for C++ type: Base*
```

Why it handled correctly the Base* returned by makeDerived() and refuses to work with Base* contained in std::vector? How can I make it work?

Answer (score 3):

You can fix this by registering `Base*` as a type that can be used to point to a `BaseWrapper*`:

```
class_<BaseWrapper, noncopyable, Base*>("Base")
        .def("func", pure_virtual(&Base::func));
```

But it seems that this means that `Base` can't have a pure virtual function...

Comment: Yep, making Base::func() not pure solves the problem. Thanks, at least for this solution. But is there some workaround that does not change any existing API?

Comment: It isn't just making it not pure that solves the problem though, it is also registering `Base*` as a pointer type to BaseWrapper, unless I'm mistaken? Perhaps there is a way to coerce boost python into accepting a type with pure virtual methods as a pointer type...

Comment: Yes, I meant making func() not pure and registering Base* ptr solved the problem. Can you explain better how can I make python accept a type with pure virtuals?

Comment: Well it's boost python that rejects it. I think the place to start would be to look at the compiler error message that you get if you declare `Base*` as a pointer type for `BaseWrapper`, and leave the function as pure virtual.